# How to lowercase the text in the EditText of the searchable item?

Tags: android

I'm using a searchable item with suggestion in my Android project. It is essentially an EditText

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search.hint" 
    android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"
    android:searchSettingsDescription="@string/search.hint"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.xxx.android.provider.SearchSuggestionsProvider"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch">
</searchable>
```

When I start typing it shows as first letter uppercase. Why? I would like it to start lowercase. Is it possible?

Answer (score 25):

I'm surprised there isn't a good answer for this yet. Or maybe it's on another question that I couldn't find.

So here's my solution.

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter.AllCaps() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            return String.valueOf(source).toLowerCase();
        }
    }
});
```

All text in `editText` will be lowercase, no matter what.

You can modify the string however you like.
For example: you want all text to be lowercase AND no spaces allowed (let's say it's an email input field)

You can replace that `return ...` like with this:

```
return String.valueOf(source).toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
```

The same way you can allow or reject individual characters.
This example replaces all `e` or `E` with `3`.

```
return String.valueOf(source).replace("e", "3").replace("E", "3");
```

And so on.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: @thepatel this is very useful and the solution is very clean. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that with this code I'm getting glitches when erasing the text rapidly by holding the "backspace" button/key. Like when erasing the text "this is a text", it will add "ext" again at the end after erasing it.

Answer (score 11):

If you want the first character to be small case by default you can use - `android:capitalize="none"`. Then you will need to manually click a button to capitalize the first character. Else follow [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462797/making-sure-edittext-only-returns-single-lowercase-letters)

Comment: Well, that is supposed to be the default but it's not the case on all the phones. On my G2 running Android 2.3.3 the first letter is still capitalized, even using capitalize="none"

Comment: Strange. Works on my HTC Wildfire S running on 2.3.5

Comment: This is good, but robsf is right, it doesn't work across all phones and/or versions of the OS. Is there a universal way? I'm thinking it'll be to programatically override the keyboard launch when the user clicks in the edittext and then set the keyboard to all lowercase. Am I on the right track?

Comment: If it does not work on some phones just because manufacturers have implemented it other way, you can extend the EditText and provide a TextWatcher to it which will perform your desired task.

Comment: It is deprecated. Use inputType.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if the proposed answer works or not, but I found a bug that affected the solution I was using previously. In some keyboards (specifically Samsung ones) when the "smart text" is enabled, the chars would get duplicated.

The best solution was to create an AllLowerInputFilter class, which I basically adapted from the Android's own AllCaps implementation. It works with every keyboard I tested, with or without "smart text" enabled.

```
class AllLowerInputFilter : InputFilter {

    override fun filter(source: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, dest: Spanned?, dstart: Int, dend: Int): CharSequence? {

        for (i in start until end) {
            if (source[i].isUpperCase()) {
                val v = CharArray(end - start)
                TextUtils.getChars(source, start, end, v, 0)
                val s = String(v).toLowerCase()

                return if (source is Spanned) {
                    val sp = SpannableString(s)
                    TextUtils.copySpansFrom(source, start, end, null, sp, 0)
                    sp
                } else {
                    s
                }
            }
        }

        return null // keep original
    }
}
```

And would be used like this:

```
editText.filters = arrayOf(AllLowerInputFilter())
```

Answer (score 7):

Solution in ***kotlin***:

```
editText.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(object : InputFilter.AllCaps() {
        override fun filter(source: CharSequence?, start: Int, end: Int, dest: Spanned?, dstart: Int, dend: Int) = 
              source.toString().toLowerCase()
        })
```

Comment: Another code style for the same: 
                override fun filter(...): CharSequence? {
                    return source.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
                }

Comment: This solution has glitches. In some phones you'll see duplication of entire words.

Answer (score 6):

Try ,

```
android:digits="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a variety of inputType options, but none specifically to keep text lowercase.

You may want to look through the complete list of them here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

I would expect "textUri" would do what you want.

You can always just use the String.toLowerCase() function on the text, after it has been entered.

Otherwise, you could add add a TextWatcher to your EditText, and validate each input event, based on your specific criteria.

Comment: A sample [lower casing TextWatcher](https://gist.github.com/karolw/5176884e21511676f2020cc0ebe88d20)

Answer (score 3):

If you want the first character to be small

```
android:inputType="text"
```

Comment: Actually this is the simplest and it works

Answer (score 2):

Based on @THEPATEL's answer and discarding the AllCaps class, here's a more compact version (provided you use Java 8):

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
            (src, start, end, dest, dstart, dend) -> src.toString().toLowerCase()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide my `Kotlin` solution

```
editText.filters = arrayOf(
        yourFilter01(), // if you have
        yourFilter02(),  // if you have
        InputFilter { source, _, _, _, _, _ ->
            source.toString().toLowerCase()
        }
)
```

Comment: or:         **editText.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(
            object : InputFilter.AllCaps() {
                override fun filter(
                    source: CharSequence,
                    start: Int,
                    end: Int,
                    dest: Spanned?,
                    dstart: Int,
                    dend: Int
                ): CharSequence? {
                    return source.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
                }
            }
        )**

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:
If `android:inputType` is set to `"textPassword"` then everything is lowercase.
So if it is set to `"textVisiblePassword"` then everything is in lowercase.